# Remove \r\n' from string in python 3

Tags: python, string

Given this string

```
b'141\r\n'
```

got by `serial.readlines()`, how can I extrapolate 141, or however the number in its position? Actually I can remove `b'` simply by using `string[2:]` but I cannot remove the remainder in this way.
`string.replace` does not work I don't know why.

The number of figures in the number may vary. Is there a smart way to avoid this problem?

Comment: `string.rstrip()`

Comment: `b'141\r\n'` this isn't a string. It's the representation of a python `bytes` object. If it were the string then it would look like `"b'141\\r\\n'"`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell @Amitay Dror I think he copied-pasted my question. `string.rstrip` does not work

Comment: `b'141\r\n'.strip()`

Comment: @T.sala Ah OK. Let's mark that as spam

Comment: If `b'` is actually part of the value, you'll need to show some broader context for how you obtain it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so theres two questions here. Is your object

```
b = b'141\r\n'
```

or

```
s = "b'141\\r\\n'"
```

If it's the former

```
b.decode().strip()
```

if it's the latter

```
import re
re.search(r'\d+', s).group(0)
```